# Astronomical number sequence

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, knowledge

> 1 2 3 0 [4] 4 0 [4] [1]
>   5 6 7 0 [4] 8 0 [4] [1]
>   9 10 11 0 [4] 12 0 [4] [1]
>   We're gonna [1] [2] [3] [4] tonight!

Can you name $[1]$, $[2]$, $[3]$ and $[4]$?

Comment: jafe, r13(Whfg nf V tbg gur Orr Trrf fbat fghpx va lbhe urnq ntnva, lbh'ir whfg tbar naq tbggra guvf fbat fghpx va zl urnq ntnva!) ;P

Comment: @El-Guest muahahahah!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> [1] Rock [2] Around [3] The [4] Clock, from Bill Haley and the Comets - Rock around the clock.
>
>  One, Two, Three O'clock, Four O'clock rock,
>  Five, Six, Seven O'clock, Eight O'clock rock.
>  Nine, Ten, Eleven O'clock, Twelve O'clock rock,
>  We're gonna rock around the clock tonight.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that JonMark Perry's answer is probably correct, but I still want to chip in with my answer:

> [1] = 1
>  [2] = 3
>  [3] = 3
>  [4] = 7

because

> The phrase `We're gonna [1] [2] [3] [4] tonight!` implies that the placeholders either stand for Words or numbers that can be read or spelled like words. Since the sequence does not make sense to me when I put in words, I think that the numbers can be read out. --> [leetspeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet) comes into my mind. We're gonna leet tonight!

Comment: rot13[j3 e t0aa4 e0k0e 2avgr]